# How to fund an account in a Stellar private network?

Tags: testnet, stellar

I know, I can set-up a Stellar private network as described [here](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/issues/1152). Once set-up, an account needs to be created as described [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/create-account.html). The Stellar documentation says -

> In order to prevent people from making a huge number of unnecessary
>   accounts, each account must have a minimum balance of 20 lumens
>   (lumens are the built-in currency of the Stellar network). Since you
>   don’t yet have any lumens, though, you can’t pay for an account. In
>   the real world, you’ll usually pay an exchange that sells lumens in
>   order to create a new account.

It goes on to say -

> On Stellar’s test network, however, you can ask Friendbot, our
>   friendly robot with a very fat wallet, to create an account for you.

So, on the main network, lumens need to be purchased at an exchange. On the test network, there is the bot. What should I use on my private network?

Answer (score 2):

Visit: https://galactictalk.org/d/735-is-it-possible-to-build-my-own-blockchain-private-blockchain-on-stellar/2

> The stellar network doesn't use mining. It doesn't even have "blocks". I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for.
>
> When you start a private network you get the root account key in the logs with 100 billion Lumens. It should work like the public network. If you want to remove the need for Lumens you would need to modify the software.